# Парсинг Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, html, парсер, requests, selenium-webdriver

Есть достаточно противный сайт, на к-м множество эл-в генерируются при взаимодействии клиента с сайтом, поэтому необходимо использовать веб-драйвер и библиотеку Selenium (через отправку запросов не получилось), но и тут возникают проблемы.

Имеются след. эл-ты филтрации:

[image: Имеются след. эл-ты фильтрации:]

При нажатии на иконку фильтрации открывается форма, где можно выбрать (допустим, кнопка "Дата") "Выбрать всё", даты каждой пятницы с 2020 по 2022, "Ок" и "Отмена".

Исследование кода страницы даёт след. рез-т:

[image: Исследование кода страницы даёт след. рез-т (для даты)]

Однако при `but = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'x-auto-157'); but.click()` ничего не происходит.
При нажатии на эту кнопку в браузере (или вручную в веб-драйвере) на странице генерируется html-код в теге div (дочерний тегу body):

[image: Генерируемый код:]

Которого, соответственно, нет в ином случае.

Доп. информация: на странице так же имеется тег iframe, к к-му я пытался обращаться через `driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.ID, '__gwt_historyFrame'))`, что так же не привело к желаемому результату. Кроме того, при нажатии и открытии формы фильтрации отправляется POST-запрос (его так же пытался отправить через requests, но не сработало). Так же скажу, что исследовал разные events и допускал, что клик не привязан к тегу img, однако обращение к родительским тегам так же не приводило ни к какому результату. Возможно, стоит обратить внимание на то, что на одном изображении есть "стрелочка", при прокликивании которой данные сортируются по убыванию/возрастанию, и на ней же кнопка с вызовом формы фильтрации (возможно, следует наводиться на определённые части эл-та или составить какое-то другое комбинированное условие для срабатывания события, id #x-auto-157 - это id изображения "Дата" в целом, но не конкретно кнопки фильтрации или "стрелочки" сортировки, при этом title="" тега меняется при наведении в определённые части эл-та).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задачу решил, эвенты действительно нужно выполнять последовательно (сначала навестись на эл-т, а после сместить курсор и кликнуть по кнопке фильтрации).

```
 but = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'x-auto-209')
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element_with_offset(to_element=but, xoffset=40, yoffset=0).click()
    actions.perform()
```